# Нейросеть классифицирующая изображения с обучением в реальном времени

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Доброе время суток! Потребовалось написать нейросеть, которая разделяет изображения на две категории: "да" и "нет". И выглядит это как умная подсказка пользователю, которая обучается на основе действий этого же юзера, тоесть в реальном времени.

Начал гуглить, но вот не шарю до конца - как строить запросы, ибо "neural network image classifier" дает понятие, но нигде нет "обучения в реальном времени", да и модели предлагают уже готовые, если использовать тот же openCV.

Прошу помочь с наведением или поиском на статьи. По-правде, даже не знаю, что и как искать. Подойдет любой язык для реализации. За ранее - большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

По факту нужно просто делать один шаг градиентного спуска с полученными данными (и данными, и таргетом).
Основная проблема в том, что будет очень легко переобучиться. Надо настраивать learning rate, добавлять аугментации (если релевантно), копить примеры, чтобы хватило на 1 батч или пробовать другие приёмы.

Пример можно посмотреть у меня в github: https://github.com/Erlemar/digit-draw-recognize
Это на tensorflow, но суть можно понять и переписать на используемый framework.